# How to call a specific word from csv file using python

Tags: python, database, csv, row, multiple-columns

Supposed if I have a `.csv` file with two columns `A, B` so if I call column A row 3 then how to print column B row 3 data . Please help me out as I am beginner at code.

I just want to call a input value and print same row value form next column.

This is my code:

if "Hello" in msg:

```
     with open('data.csv', "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        chat = {}

        for row in reader:
            key = row[0]
            chat[key] = row[1:]
    try:
        gotreply = chat[msg]
    except KeyError:
        gotreply = 'null'

    print(gotreply)

     if gotreply == 'null':
        print("Sorry! I didn't understand. I'm still learning.")
    else:
        print("Input Again")
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to hande a csv file. Can you post example data and a script that attempts a solution? Its only a few lines of code to read a file into a list of rows with the `csv` module. `pandas` is popular too. Find some examples, pick a method and then give us a basic program to work from.

Comment: if "Hello" in msg:

         with open('data.csv', "r") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            chat = {}

            for row in reader:
                key = row[0]
                chat[key] = row[1:]
        try:
            gotreply = chat[msg]
        except KeyError:
            gotreply = 'null'

        print(gotreply)

         if gotreply == 'null':
            print("Sorry! I didn't understand. I'm still learning.")
        else:
            print("Input Again")

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you asking, but you could do

```
import pandas as pd

foo_df = pd.read_csv('files/example.csv')

if foo_df.A[2] == "c":
    print(foo_df.B[2])
```

Comment: Hi  thanks, it gave me a good idea about calling a specific data, but my question was calling the column B data , from user input i:e user will call from column A row and gets output as column B in same row.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend familiarizing yourself with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#csv-text-files) as an elegant way to parse data.

Example .csv:

```
A,B
a,b
b,c
c,d
d,e
```

where A and B are your column names.

`pandas.read_csv()` will read a .csv and put it in a Dataframe. [Check out the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv) and give it a go.

```
import pandas as pd

foo_df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/example.csv')

print(foo_df)
```

should return

```
   A  B
0  a  b
1  b  c
2  c  d
3  d  e
```

From there, it should just be a matter of taking a look at the docs to retrieve what you want from the dataframe.

Comment: Hi  thanks, it gave me a good idea about calling a data, but my question was calling the column B data , from user input i:e user will call from column A row and gets output as column B in same row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a beginner and this is my first post here so I'll try to help you out.

First I assume your CSV file has headers and I assume your headers are called "A" and "B".

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    row_count = 1
    for i in csv_reader:
        if row_count == 4:
            print(i[1])  # prints second column of third row
        row_count += 1
```

There's probably a more efficient way but I'm new to the game too.

Answer (score 0):

When I first started I also had some doubts like that. [Pandas Slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) will be of help to you.

First import Pandas module as 'pd' (import pandas as pd) as it the most used form and will be easier for you to adapt.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14], ['tony', 12]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B'])
```

This will create a sample Data Frame or simple 'df':

```
      A     B
0   tom     10
1   nick    15
2   juli    14
3   tony    12
```

Using one of the most common slicers in pandas df.loc you can get the result you want:

```
df.loc[2,'B']
```

This will return column 'B' row 3 as you mentioned. Remember that in Python first index start at 0 not 1. That's why we are using '2' for row number three.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi Gustavo thanks, it gave me a good idea about calling a specific data, but my question was calling the column B data , from user input i:e user will call from column A row and gets output as column B in same row.